# Subspaces involving differentiable functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is the question I don't know how to deal with. It's from Friedberg's text.

[image]

Am I supposed to show that the set of derivatives of all differentiable functions holds under scalar multiplication and addition or is the idea here to just recognize that all differentiable functions are continuous functions, so this holds trivially?

There's no solution manual and he has no examples regarding differentiable functions, so I'm stuck, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is asking you to show whether or not this set, say $D$, satisfies the subspace axioms:

a) $0 \in D$

b) $f,g\in D \implies f+g\in D$

c) $h\in D, \lambda \in R \implies \lambda h\in D$

Using the properties you likely know about derivatives, determine whether or not these hold.